# How to have a search box and submit button on the same line (using jquery mobile)

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

The submit button always start on a new line by itself on jquery mobile, is style the way to solve this?

```
<form method="post" action="../cgi-bin/search.pl">
    <input type="search" name="sterms" id="sterms" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="search startags" style="background:#dddddd; " >
    <input type="submit" data-mini="false" data-inline="true" data-icon="search" data-icon-notext ">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `float:left`

```
 <form method="post" action="../cgi-bin/search.pl">
<input type="search" name="sterms"  id="sterms" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="search startags" style="float:left;background:#dddddd; " >
<input type="submit" data-mini="false" style="float:left" data-inline="true" data-icon="search" data-icon-notext ">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the tags correctly, they will show up correctly, for example, you had a double quote (`"`) at the end of one of your intputs and no slashes (`/`) at their end. Further more, other css code may influence them, but normally, as inputs are inline elements, placing them below one another should still show them up next to each other.

```
<form method="post" action="../cgi-bin/search.pl">
    <input type="search" name="sterms" id="sterms" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="search startags" style="background:#dddddd; " />
    <input type="submit" data-mini="false" data-inline="true" data-icon="search" data-icon-notext />
</form>
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xgx3a/)**